# Dynamic JTabbed Pane

Tags: java, xml, swing, parsing

I am making a xml parser where xml is read from a file the issue is that i have to set tabs dynamically at run time where title is fetched from the xml file, also i have to split certain portion of the parsed String before displaying them in the JTable. I am keeping my code below:

```
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.Font;
    import java.awt.GridLayout;
    import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
    import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.List;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
    import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
    import javax.swing.JTable;
    import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
    import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
    import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

    import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

    public class XmlGui extends JFrame {
        public XmlGui() {/*Default Constructor*/}

        public static void main(String[] args) throws SAXException, IOException,ParserConfigurationException {
            int check = 0;
            String TabTitle;
            SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
            XmlBack xmlBack = new XmlBack();
            saxParser.parse(new File("C:\\Documents and Settings\\ASU\\Desktop\\Xml File\\VG_MachineData.xml"), xmlBack); 
            new XmlGui().drawFrame(xmlBack.varGroupVariables);
        }

        public void drawFrame(List<VarGroupVariable> varGroupVariables) {
            setTitle("The Xml Parser");
            addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            });
            setSize(800, 500);
            JTabbedPane TabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
            JPanel jplInnerPanel1 = createInnerPanel();
            jplInnerPanel1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            //Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>();
            JTable table = new JTable();

            table.setModel(new VarGroupVariableModel(varGroupVariables));
            table.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 16));
            // Create Second Tab.
            JPanel jplInnerPanel2 = createInnerPanel();
            TabbedPanePane.addTab(" DEMO TABBED ", jplInnerPanel2);
            jplInnerPanel2.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        }

        protected JPanel createInnerPanel() {
            JPanel jplPanel = new JPanel();
            JLabel jlbDisplay = new JLabel();
            jlbDisplay.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            jplPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
            jplPanel.add(jlbDisplay);
            return jplPanel;
        }
    }

sample xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<HMI_Data Version="1.0" MaschinenNR.="XXXXXX" Date="21-10-2009">
   <VarGroup Name="VG_MachineData">
      <Variable Name="Mold1.sv_rMoldStroke">
         <Typ>REAL</Typ>
         <Value>6.000000e+02</Value>
      </Variable>
      <Variable Name="Core1.sv_rMaxSpeedFwd">
         <Typ>REAL</Typ>
         <Value>5.000000e+01</Value>
      </Variable>
      <Variable Name="Core1.sv_rMaxSpeedBwd">
         <Typ>REAL</Typ>
         <Value>5.000000e+01</Value>
      </Variable>
      <Variable Name="Core1.sv_rMaxPressureFwd">
         <Typ>REAL</Typ>
         <Value>1.450000e+02</Value>
      </Variable>
      <Variable Name="Core1.sv_rMaxPressureBwd">
         <Typ>REAL</Typ>
         <Value>1.450000e+02</Value>
      </Variable>
      <Variable Name="Core1.sv_rImpulseFilterLimit">
         <Typ>REAL</Typ>
         <Value>0.000000e+00</Value>
      </Variable>
```

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: don't you just need a FOR loop then?

Comment: Can you provide a sample output of your table??

Comment: The output is showing one tab with jtable and table contains four columns and 10k rows. All i want is to add tabs at run time. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: don't see you trying to add tabs dynamically - please don't show random code, but a SSCCE demonstrating the exact problem where you are stuck